# Visual Studio UWP how to add the source image using C# instead of XAML?

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017

been trying to figure this out for a while now to no success. I dragged the image tool on the MainPage and named it MyImage.

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="Assets/luigi.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="285,400,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.587,0.507"/>
```

C#:

```
private void ImageCheckBox_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyImage.Source = I CAN'T FIGURE OUT WHAT TO DO HERE;
        }
```

As you can see I added the image Assets/luigi.jpg in the XAML code, but I want  to use a checkbox event to add the image and for that I'll need to do it in C#. I already got the result I wanted by just setting the opacity of the image to 0% and then Changing it to 100% when I click on the checkbox, but I would like to add the image through C# mainly as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `BitmapImage` and `ms-appx:///` before url to set source.

```
MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/MyImage.png"));
```

As suggested in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source#setting-source-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on where you need to get the file from. The source of an image tag is an  [ImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.imagesource?view=xamarin-forms) It has these Static methods that make a new ImageSource
FromFile(String)
FromResource(String, Assembly)
FromResource(String, Type)
FromStream(Func)
FromUri(Uri)

So it could be 
MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromURI("https://myimageURL");

Comment: Ok. I added the image to my Assets folder. Let me try to figure it out, but I'll come back in a few minutes if I can't. If you know the answer feel free to provide it and I'll mark it as correct when I come back

Comment: Haven't been able to figure this out.